# Error loading optional module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, barcode

I'm trying to use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision_2) due to it's multiple barcode scanner.
I run their own code (which is available on [pub.dev](http://pub.dev)) but it doesn't detect any barcode and give me some log :

```
W/DynamiteModule(18708): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode not found.
I/DynamiteModule(18708): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
W/DynamiteModule(18708): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode not found.
I/DynamiteModule(18708): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:0
E/Vision  (18708): Error loading optional module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module foun
d. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

and it repeats over and over.

i do all requirements as publisher has mentioned but still not working.

this so important to me i need to fix it , i asked once but no one answered. your answers are so mean to me thanks.

Comment: What device are you having this error on? I get this error on *all* apps that scan QR codes on a Pixel 6 Pro, Android 12, build 220105.007. It may not even be an issue with the package but with something in Android itself.

Comment: @Dan Yes it is same to me, I tried on different devices but it didn't work again. I don't know where is the problem too.